# What is the best way to 'fan-out' a, say, Twilio webhook callback?

Tags: api, twilio

I use Twilio's WhatsApp API.

Incoming messages, status updates, are sent to my server via callbacks - standard stuff.

I also use several services which ride on the same callbacks - e.g., Frontapp, Missive, and the like.

What is the best way to 'fan out' callbacks to the other services? Is making a separate HTTP post call to each of the other service, mimicking the format of Twilio's callback the best way?

Intuitively, I shouldn't be able to use HTTP redirect, because it'd only allow me to forward, and not fan out the call. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I’d go with a simple function (e.g. Lambda, Zapier, etc.) that will:

- receive the webhook from Twilio
- respond ‘200’ (otherwise Twilio will *try the [`fallback Url`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security/availability-reliability#fallback-urls)*)
- replay the payload to other listeners

Your stretch goals could include:

- async delivery/retries (write the payload to a DB, listeners pickup on that write and deliver/retry their respective services, independently)
- Twilio signature checks (duh)

Happy dev

Comment: Just a note, Twilio will not retry failed webhook requests, though you can set up a [fallback URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security/availability-reliability#fallback-urls) that will be tried in the event the original webhook fails.